# View to insert records into history table and then find changes with Except query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016, view

I want to insert records to a history table and show the changes from the previous day in a view. The script works, but when I try to create a view I get an error message that

> incorrect syntax near insert expecting ( select or with'.

How would I do that with a view? SQL Server 2016

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[Acc-Faculty-Changes] 
AS 
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Acc-Faculty-History]

       (
       [Run Date]
      ,[ID]
      ,[Name]
      ,[First]
      ,[Last]
      ,[Email]
      ,[Department]
      ,[Phone Number]
      ,[Mobile Number]
      )

SELECT DISTINCT 

       CURRENT_TIMESTAMP [Run Date]
      ,RTRIM(ISNULL(FL.INSTRCTR_ID_NUM, SPACE(0))) as ID
      ,RTRIM(ISNULL(NM.FIRST_NAME + ' ' + NM.LAST_NAME, SPACE(0))) as Name
      ,RTRIM(ISNULL(NM.FIRST_NAME, SPACE(0))) as First
      ,RTRIM(ISNULL(NM.LAST_NAME, SPACE(0))) as Last
      ,RTRIM(ISNULL(NM.EMAIL_ADDRESS, SPACE(0))) as Email
      ,RTRIM(ISNULL(SM.DIVISION_CDE, SPACE(0))) as  Department
      ,AM.PHONE [Phone Number]
      ,NM.MOBILE_PHONE [Mobile Number]
      FROM DevPrd.dbo.FACULTY_LOAD_TABLE FL
      INNER JOIN DevPrd.dbo.YEAR_TERM_TABLE YT
      ON FL.YR_CDE = YT.YR_CDE
      AND FL.TRM_CDE = YT.TRM_CDE
      INNER JOIN DevPrd.dbo.NAME_MASTER NM
      ON NM.ID_NUM = FL.INSTRCTR_ID_NUM
      --INNER JOIN DevPrd.dbo.FACULTY_MASTER FM
      --ON NM.ID_NUM = FM.ID_NUM
      INNER JOIN DevPrd.dbo.ADDRESS_MASTER AM
      ON NM.ID_NUM = AM.ID_NUM
      --WHERE FM.ACTIVE = 'Y'
      --AND NM.CURRENT_ADDRESS <> '*LHP'
      INNER JOIN DevPrd.dbo.SECTION_MASTER SM
      ON FL.YR_CDE = SM.YR_CDE
      AND FL.TRM_CDE = SM.TRM_CDE
    
      WHERE 
    
      YT.TRM_BEGIN_DTE <= dateadd(mi, 30, FORMAT(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'd') ) --set to day of course 
      AND YT.TRM_END_DTE >= dateadd(mi, 30, FORMAT(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'd'))
```

--View change

```
    SELECT        ID, Name, First, Last, Email, Department, [Phone Number], [Mobile Number]
    FROM            DEVReporting.dbo.[Acc-Faculty-History]
      WHERE [Run Date] = (SELECT MAX([Run Date Top 2]) [Max Run Date]
                            FROM
                            (SELECT TOP 2 [Run Date] [Run Date Top 2]
                              FROM [DEVReporting].[dbo].[Acc-Faculty-History]
                              GROUP BY [Run Date]
                            ORDER BY [Run Date] DESC) X)
    EXCEPT
    SELECT        ID, Name, First, Last, Email, Department, [Phone Number], [Mobile Number]
    FROM            DEVReporting.dbo.[Acc-Faculty-History]
      WHERE [Run Date] = (SELECT Min([Run Date Top 2]) [Max Run Date]
                            FROM
                            (SELECT TOP 2 [Run Date] [Run Date Top 2]
                              FROM [DEVReporting].[dbo].[Acc-Faculty-History]
                              GROUP BY [Run Date]
                            ORDER BY [Run Date] DESC) X)
```

Comment: Are you trying to put `INSERT INTO [dbo].[Acc-Faculty-History]` inside of your view?

Comment: I need to insert the records for the last Run Date first, then open the view to see changes. Does the insert have to go in a stored procedure or script task in SSIS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your response in the comments it sounds like you were trying to use an `INSERT` statement inside of your View's definition. That is not allowed and therefore not proper T-SQL syntax which explains the error you received:

> incorrect syntax near insert expecting ( select or with

Views are essentially just a placeholder object for a DQL (`SELECT`) statement. Instead, if you want this code to be re-usable, you can create a [stored procedure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/create-a-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-ver15) like so:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Acc-Faculty-Changes] AS

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Acc-Faculty-History]
(
   [Run Date]
  ,[ID]
  ,[Name]
  ,[First]
  ,[Last]
  ,[Email]
  ,[Department]
  ,[Phone Number]
  ,[Mobile Number]
)
SELECT DISTINCT
   CURRENT_TIMESTAMP [Run Date]
  ,RTRIM(ISNULL(FL.INSTRCTR_ID_NUM, SPACE(0))) as ID
  ,RTRIM(ISNULL(NM.FIRST_NAME + ' ' + NM.LAST_NAME, SPACE(0))) as Name
  ,RTRIM(ISNULL(NM.FIRST_NAME, SPACE(0))) as First
  ,RTRIM(ISNULL(NM.LAST_NAME, SPACE(0))) as Last
  ,RTRIM(ISNULL(NM.EMAIL_ADDRESS, SPACE(0))) as Email
  ,RTRIM(ISNULL(SM.DIVISION_CDE, SPACE(0))) as  Department
  ,AM.PHONE [Phone Number]
  ,NM.MOBILE_PHONE [Mobile Number]
FROM DevPrd.dbo.FACULTY_LOAD_TABLE FL
INNER JOIN DevPrd.dbo.YEAR_TERM_TABLE YT
  ON FL.YR_CDE = YT.YR_CDE
  AND FL.TRM_CDE = YT.TRM_CDE
  INNER JOIN DevPrd.dbo.NAME_MASTER NM
  ON NM.ID_NUM = FL.INSTRCTR_ID_NUM
  --INNER JOIN DevPrd.dbo.FACULTY_MASTER FM
  --ON NM.ID_NUM = FM.ID_NUM
INNER JOIN DevPrd.dbo.ADDRESS_MASTER AM
  ON NM.ID_NUM = AM.ID_NUM
  --WHERE FM.ACTIVE = 'Y'
  --AND NM.CURRENT_ADDRESS <> '*LHP'
INNER JOIN DevPrd.dbo.SECTION_MASTER SM
  ON FL.YR_CDE = SM.YR_CDE
  AND FL.TRM_CDE = SM.TRM_CDE

WHERE

  YT.TRM_BEGIN_DTE <= dateadd(mi, 30, FORMAT(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'd') ) --set to day of course 
  AND YT.TRM_END_DTE >= dateadd(mi, 30, FORMAT(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'd'))
```

Comment: Thanks, so View is only for View

Comment: @ERPISE Correct, a View is only for [DQL](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_query_language) statements, generally `SELECT` only statements; and cannot be used for storing queries that modify data (such as `INSERTS` or `UPDATES`).